# Minipage won't format properly

Tags: xetex, minipage

I need help with this. Why `Block B` is being printed below `Block A`? I need to have it right to `Block A`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Font size - 10pt, 11pt or 12pt.

\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry} % Document margins.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{{\sffamily Last update: \today}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Get rid of the default rule in the header.

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} % Start the left-hand side of the page.
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment.
Block A.
\end{minipage} % End the left-hand side of the page.

\hfill % ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth} % Start the right-hand side of the page.
\vspace{0pt} % Trick for alignment.
Block B.
\end{minipage} % End right-hand side of the page.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % Font size - 10pt, 11pt or 12pt.

\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry} % Document margins.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{{\sffamily Last update: \today}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Get rid of the default rule in the header.

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% Start the left-hand side of the page.
Block A.
\end{minipage}% End the left-hand side of the page
\hfill % ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth}% Start the right-hand side of the page.
Block B.
\end{minipage}% End right-hand side of the page.

\end{document}
```

I have moved the spaces before your `%` as these will produce unwanted white space in the output, I removed the paragraph breaks between the minipages and removed the `vspace` "trick" which would prevent the minipages aligning on the baseline of their first row.

Comment: I need to say that `minipage` have strange behaviour. Should I go for `columns` instead of `minipage`? Or maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: `minipage` are just positioned the same way a letter is positioned they really don't have any behaviour at all strange or otherwise. You haven't given much indication of the intention of the layout but using twocolumn mode or a table are possibilities depending what you need.

Comment: I need to make two columns on one page AND I don't want to bother about that I have wrong formatting (spaces) that can screw up all my work.

Comment: why one column wider than the other? In TeX you always have to worry about spaces, then input `AB` and the input `A B` are different: white space in the source may produce white space in the output.